# Is is possible to use Hung thread interrupter to multi node Websphere Network Deployment environment?

Tags: websphere

I have recently come across an utility from IBM site which when installed in the WebSphere environment can interrupt the hung thread.  It is called Hung Thread Interrupter (HTI). When I installed this in a single node environment it works fine but when I install the HTI is an environment which is spread across multiple nodes, the HTI files are not getting updated properly and exception message is present in the console.  Can anyone let me know whether HTI will work for multi node environment?  I could not find any information in the HTI documentation regarding this.

Below is the link from IBM site which explains about the HTI
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/downloads/hungthread.html#icomments

Comment: What "exception message"?

Comment: This is the message,
"CWLAA6003: Explanation: Could not display the portlet, an exception has occurred. User action: Check the server logs, there will be a warning message associated with this error of the form " while rendering a page...", this message will contain more detail of the error. Mostly likely cause is the console module as been uninstalled. "

Comment: And there is no logs for this in the server..